# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined at HTMLDivElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 8 tiles that I want to add an eventlistener to. I loop through the 8 tiles with the following code:

```
<script>
var lt = document.querySelectorAll('.feature-listings .leadin_text');
var ll = document.querySelectorAll('.feature-listings .leadin_links a');

for(i = 0; i < lt.length; i++) {

console.log(ll[i].href);

console.log(lt[i]);

    lt[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        
        //window.location= ll[i].href;

        console.log("clicked" + ll[i].href);

    });
}

</script>
```

Testing in the console, I successfully get both my href and the div(.leadin_text) that I want the click applied to.

https://www.example.com/mylistings.html/listing.springfield.91226914
(index):852 <div class=​"leadin_text">​…​​
(index):850 https://www.example.com/mylistings.html/listing.1925199-63122-lornehill-road-springfield-rm-r2c2z2.90284903
(index):852 <div class=​"leadin_text">​…​​
.
.
.

However, when I click on a tile executing the line:
console.log("clicked" + ll[i].href);

I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.

What I really want is for the user to click on the tile and go to the href.

Comment: Make your code runnable here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you need to specify that you're `let`ting the variable `i` be created. This locks the variable into the current loop's block.

You should change your `for` loop to read like shown:
`for(let i = 0; i < lt.length; i++)`